# Length of neuro-physiological signals of emotion compared to feeling time

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, emotion, neurophysiology

In "Determinants of Emotion Duration and Underlying Psychological and Neural Mechanisms" by Verduyn et al. discuss how certain physiological signals are outlasted by actual feelings:

> In particular, whereas the duration of expressive
>   (e.g., facial expression; [1]), and (neuro)physiological components
>   (e.g., cardiovascular recovery; [2]) seems to rarely exceed a few
>   minutes, feelings and associated cognitions may persist for hours or
>   longer (e.g., [3], [4]).

Is this true for all external physiological signals including Galvanic Skin Response (GSR) and Electromyography (EMG)? I would find this surprising given that there is evidence of the central nervous system being related relating physical to social pain, as shown in "[Acetaminophen Reduces Social Pain: Behavioral and Neural Evidence](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/44673230_Acetaminophen_Reduces_Social_Pain_Behavioral_and_Neural_Evidence)" Dewall et al., so I would expect some external evidence of this physical pain.

---

[1] Ekman, Paul, and Wallace V. Friesen. "Felt, false, and miserable smiles." Journal of nonverbal behavior 6.4 (1982): 238-252.

[2] L. Fredrickson, Barbara, and Robert W. Levenson. "Positive emotions speed recovery from the cardiovascular sequelae of negative emotions." Cognition & emotion 12.2 (1998): 191-220.

[3] Nolen-Hoeksema, Susan, and Jannay Morrow. "Effects of rumination and distraction on naturally occurring depressed mood." Cognition & Emotion 7.6 (1993): 561-570.

[4] Verduyn, Philippe, Iven Van Mechelen, and Francis Tuerlinckx. "The relation between event processing and the duration of emotional experience." Emotion 11.1 (2011): 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "[Simultaneous acquisition of corrugator electromyography and functional magnetic resonance imaging: A new method for objectively measuring affect and neural activity concurrently](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3206735/)" Aaron et al. use face EMG to measure emotional reaction to photos. As shown in the figure below, the response only lasts a few seconds:

[image: emg figure]

Getting a GSR response is more complicated due to the noise in the reading. In "[Time-series analysis for rapid event-related skin conductance responses](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2772899/)" by Bach et al., the authors figure out a mathematical approach for figuring out the event-related response. Both via a smoothed fitted gamma distribution and PCA component analysis are used below:

[image: gsr response]

Both response measures seem to return to reference levels after 30 minutes.